# Find folders of a given age, then filter for a given size and delete the matching folders?

Tags: find

I've been having trouble with this for some time. Here is what I finally came up with that seems to work, though I have very limited abilities with piping.

I'm guessing this is a poor way to achieve my goal, are there some simpler ways I could do this that would be more efficient?

```
$ find /home/data/cam*/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -mtime +30 \
    -exec du -sm {} \;| awk '{if ( $1 > 3000 ) print $2}' | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty good actually.  Assuming the `/home/data/cam*/* -maxdepth 0` part is fine, and assuming your directory names don't contain newlines, I'd do it like this:

```
find /home/data/cam*/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -mtime +30 -exec du -sm {} + | \
    awk '$1 > 3000' | cut -f 2- | xargs rm -rf
```

`-exec du -sm {} +` is an optimisation, it doesn't run `du` for each directory.  And `awk '$1 > 3000' | cut -f 2-` makes sure this still works if your directory names contain spaces.

Comment: ok great, I saw some stuff like that around online but I didnt know what it was for, thank you